# Error con un Chat en un Modal conserva la consultas anteriores

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Antes que Hola

Tengo este Codigo para un chat y lo que pasa es que cada vez que abro un chat nuevo conserva los otros anteriores ya he buscado el error pero no lo veo si hay alguien que pueda ver que me ayude.

**CODE BOTTON**

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal" data-id="11" id="getUser" class="chat__friend" info="This is some information for our tooltip.">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
```

**CODE MODAL**

```
        <div id="view-modal" class="modal_fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
             <div class="modal-dialog"> 
                  <div class="modal-content"> 

                      <button type="button" class="close_modal_chat" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button> 

                       <div class="modal-body"> 

                           <div id="modal-loader"  >
                            <img class="img_modal" src="./img/loading_data.gif"><br>
                            <br>
                            <button type="button" class="btn_modal" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
                           </div>

                           <!-- content will be load here -->                          
                           <div id="dynamic-content"></div>

                        </div> 
                 </div> 
              </div>
       </div><!-- /.modal -->    

    </div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click', '#getUser', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var uid = $(this).data('id');   // it will get id of clicked row

        $('#dynamic-content').html(''); // leave it blank before ajax call
        $('#modal-loader').show();      // load ajax loader

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/new/chat_user.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'id='+uid,
            dataType: 'html'
        })
        .done(function(data){
            console.log(data);  
            $('#dynamic-content').html('');    
            $('#dynamic-content').html(data); // load response 
            $('#modal-loader').hide();        // hide ajax loader   
        })
        .fail(function(){
            $('#dynamic-content').html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i> Something went wrong, Please try again...');
            $('#modal-loader').hide();
        });

    });

});

</script>
```

**CODE CHAT**

```
<?php

    require_once 'conectarbd.php';
    require ("function.php");
     if(isset($_POST["id"]))  
 {  
      $output = '';  
      $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE userID='".$_POST["id"]."'";  
      $result = mysql_query($query);  
      while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
            $user_id = $data['userID'];

           $output = '  
            <div class="all_content_chat">                  
                <div class="wall_messages_content_user">

                    <div class="name_user_post_modal"> 
                        <img class="modal_img" src="./img/avatar_default.png" alt="">   
                        <div>  
                            <p class="friend__name">'.$user_id.'</p>  
                        </div>  
                    </div>

                    <div class="wall_messages_content_chat" id="messages_private_chat"></div>

                </div>
                <div class="wall_messages_user_text">
                    <div class="messages_chat_box">
                        <input class="input_messages_chat_user" id="messages" type="text" placeholder="Type Message Hit Enter"></input>
                        <a class="message__send" onclick=""></a>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>  

           ';  
      }  
      echo $output;  
 }  
 // '.get_emoticons_messages().'
?>  


    <!-- **Javascript jquery, ajax Of chat** -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

    ////////////////// scroll a messages new 

            $(document).ready(function(){
                var out, isScrolledToBottom;

                out = document.getElementById("messages_private_chat"); // outer container of messages


                // initial load of chat                     ////**Chat post id
                $('#messages_private_chat').load("messages_private_load.php?id=<?php echo $user_id; ?>", function() {
                  out = document.getElementById("messages_private_chat"); // re-reference after a jQuery .load() as it removes the original dom element and add a new one
                  scrollToBottom(true);
                });


                // check for chatter every second
                setInterval(function() {

                    isScrolledToBottom = checkIfScrolledBottom();

                    $('#messages_private_chat').load("messages_private_load.php?id=<?php echo $user_id; ?>", function() {
                      out = document.getElementById("messages_private_chat"); // re-reference after a jQuery .load() as it removes the original dom element and add a new one
                      scrollToBottom(isScrolledToBottom);
                    });

                },1000);

                function checkIfScrolledBottom() {
                    // allow for 1px inaccuracy by adding 1
                    return out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight <= out.scrollTop + 1;
                }

                function scrollToBottom(scrollDown) {
                    if (scrollDown)
                    out.scrollTop = out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight;
                }
                //setTimeout(function() { $("#chat-feed").scrollTop($("#chat-feed")[0].scrollHeight);}, 1200);
            });

    </script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes puesto un console.log en el done. Qué resultado te da cada vez que ejecutas un chat? Por otra parte creo que el PHP no es correcto, ya que siempre consultas a la bbdd por un id, y luego muestras el id encontrado en la consulta... Que es el mismo (para eso con usar el del post te sobra)

Comment: No te funciono el código de la demo ?¿

Adjunta algún error/investigación y te podremos ayudar

Comment: Hola amigo mira  tengo ese code y lo que pasa es que conserva los datos  pero no se porque el Modal esta bien yo creo que el error esta en el *DIV* del chat porque le pido los datos via *$_GET* al chat y es ahi donde yo creo que esta error o que cres? @CarlosGª-muñoz